# Bash and Python signal behaviour with a pipe is inconsistent

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to catch a signal from the other side of a pipe but I can't seem to catch any signals

This is the program designed to catch all signals

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import signal
import sys

from time import sleep

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

for i in [x for x in dir(signal) if x.startswith("SIG")]:
  try:
    signum = getattr(signal,i)
    signal.signal(signum,signal_handler)
  except (OSError, RuntimeError) as m: #OSError for Python3, RuntimeError for 2
    print ("Skipping {}".format(i))
  except ValueError:
      print ("Value skip {}".format(i))

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

for a in range(0, 20):
    print a
    sleep(1)
```

I get inconsistent behaviour with different running methods and I'm not sure what would explain it. When I pipe the output of the script to `tee` I can't catch a signal that would end the program cleanly

Running method: Run script and manually Ctrl+C

```
/sub.py
```

Output:

```
Skipping SIGKILL
Skipping SIGSTOP
Value skip SIG_DFL
0
1
2
3
4
^CYou pressed Ctrl+C!
```

Running method (Run script and kill with `kill -13` (BROKEN_PIPE)):

Output:

```
Skipping SIGKILL
Skipping SIGSTOP
Value skip SIG_DFL
0
1
2
3
4
You pressed Ctrl+C!
```

Running method (Run script with piping to tee and Ctrl+C):

```
/sub.py | tee
```

Output:

```
Skipping SIGKILL
Skipping SIGSTOP
Value skip SIG_DFL
0
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sub.py", line 24, in <module>
    sleep(1)
```

OR

```
Skipping SIGKILL
Skipping SIGSTOP
Value skip SIG_DFL
0
1
2
3
4
^C
```

Notice that the `signal_handler` method is not called in either case.

---

Why is the signal handler not called? Is there a signal I can catch for graceful exit?

```
python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: A race condition perhaps? What have you done to debug?

Comment: Isn't it because the tee program is catching the signals? You can catch SIGPIPE to detect in your python program when the pipe to tee is broken

Comment: I am catching SIGPIPE though... I'm catching all signals possible. The issue is definitely some race. But why is it some race? And what is even being sent to the Python ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer focuses on python 3.7+ [(it's discussed here)](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/signal.html#note-on-sigpipe), but I imagine the same goes for python 2.7.

Calling `print` in your signal handler or calling `sys.exit()` with unflushed data on `stdout` doesn't work since by that point, `tee` is already stopped and the `stdout` pipe broken (what happens when you `Ctrl-C` a pipeline is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163561/control-which-process-gets-cancelled-by-ctrlc)).

I think the simplest fix would be to avoid using a pipe you intend to interrupt. You can achieve this by using `tail` instead of `tee`:

```bash
tail -F tmp.txt & python writer.py > tmp.txt && sleep 1; kill $!
```

If you did want to try to make the shell pipeline work, you could try rewriting your signal handler to write you message and unflushed `stdout` data to a file like this:

```py
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    f = os.open('buffer.txt', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT)
    os.dup2(f, sys.stdout.fileno())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.write(f, "You pressed Ctrl-C!".encode())
    os.close(f)
    sys.exit(1)
```

The caveat here is that this solution may have a small race condition. If the `stdout` pipe is broken first, and then your program tries flushing to `stdout` before it receives its `SIGTERM`signal, you might get a `BrokenPipeError` followed by a `SIGTERM` signal soon after which would be messy to try to handle.